# Finding the vector (direction) on surface that has the minimal temperature (given by formula)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

everybody!
The temprature on a mountain described by: $T(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$
The mountain desribed by $z = -x^2-y^2 +5$

A man, whos coordinates are $(1,1,3)$, wants to go on a direction, in which he gets cold the quickest way.

So, the algorithm is (correct me if i wrong):
 1. Find the gradient of T in (1,1,3) = (2,2,6).
 2. Find the gradient of the surface $f(x,y,z) = z+x^2+y^2 - 5 = 0$ in (1,1,3) = (2,2,1)
 3. Demand that the N that i found (gradient of the surface) will be perpendicular to the gradient of T, by dot product: $ (2,2,1) dot (2,2,c)$

Then the c I find, is the missing component, for the direction on the surface, so it is (2,2,c) in that example - (2,2,-4), Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method continuing your idea.

You should use the negative of the gradient since you are looking for the direction in which the temperature decreases the fastest. Then look for the projection of that direction onto the tangent plane of the mountain.

The gradient direction of the temperature is $\vec{t}=(-2,-2,-6)$. The normal vector of the tangent plane is the gradient of the mountain $\vec{n}=(2,2,1)$.

The projection is

$$\vec{t}-\frac{\vec{t}\cdot\vec{n}}{\vec{n}\cdot \vec{n}}\vec{n}$$

**Edit**: This method only works for this special case. user251257 gives a better method that works for general case. Here I just want to illustrate how to find the projection of a vector onto a plane.

The following picture shows the projection of a vector $\vec{t}$ onto a plane with normal vector $\vec{n}$:

[image]

Notice the little red vector is the part $\frac{\vec{t}\cdot\vec{n}}{\vec{n}\cdot \vec{n}}\vec{n}$. So subtraction gives you the projection onto the plane.

Comment: the normal is $(2,2,1)$.

Comment: @user251257: Thank you. Fixed.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for ) 
But just to make sure, is it wrong to say that dot product of (-2,-2,c) and (2,2,3) will give me that projection, right ? 
I think i saw this way in class (After I will draw it to myself little bit later, I will try to understand this formula and maybe ask about it), but we use more often the dot product of 2 vectors to find the projection, cant we apply it anyway here, in exchange calculating the projection by that subtraction, if you know what I mean ?

Comment: @user183297: When you do that, you are also demanding the $x,y$ value stay the same. But it is not the case here. You are right that they have to be perpendicular though, but this one assumption cannot lead you to the correct result.

Comment: Right, that though went threw my mind. Ok, so i hope later i will analyze why exactly we doing this subtraction. I need to analyze it deeper. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Since $z=-x^2-y^2+5$ is given explicitly, you should directly consider
$$ f(x,y) = T(x,y,z) = T(x,y,-x^2-y^2+5). $$
This leads to the steepest descent direction $-\nabla f(x,y)$, which is in general better than or equal the projection of $-\nabla T(x,y,z)$ onto the tangent space. Both directions agree here, because $\nabla_{(x,y)} T$ and $\nabla_{(x,y)} z$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: @user251257: That is a good point. Thanks.

Comment: Running against the gradient is a good idea if movement is free. But one is bound to the surface here and that means that going in $\pi/4$ direction (within the x-y plane), which are the same x-y coordinates the gradient has, will lead to a difference in $z$ where temperature is lowest.

Comment: @KittyL: My solution is the same like the answer given by .@mvw, just less physical ;)

Comment: @KittyL: oh I was silly. they are the same :(

Comment: @user251257: I was trying to figure out why they are not the same. :) But I'm still not sure what .@mvw meant. I'll keep thinking.

Comment: @user251257: They are the same when $T_xg_y=T_yg_x$ where $T$ is the temperature function, and $z=g(x,y)$ is the surface. In this special case, they are. But otherwise, your method works better.

Comment: @KittyL: ah I get what .@mvw meant. You need to stay on the surface. It makes no sense to compute a direction in the space, as you can't fly nor dig :D So projection is in fact wrong. You need to plug in the parametrization like .@mvw and I did.

Comment: @user251257: Yes, I see it. Again it only works when $T_xg_y=T_yg_x$, which happens to be the case here. I like your method better.

Answer (score 1):

The task is to walk away from the present location such that the temperature decreases as much as possible.

We are at $(1,1,3)$, the temperature gradient points at $(2,2,6)$.
If we move by $dx$ and $dy$ the change in position is
$$
dr = (dx, dy, z_x dx + z_y dy) = (dx, dy, -2(dx +dy))
$$
The change in temperature moving there is
$$
dT 
= (T_x, T_y, T_z) \cdot dr 
= (2,2,6) \cdot dr
= 2dx + 2dy - 12(dx + dy) = -10(dx+dy)
$$
With $x = r \cos \phi$, $y = r \sin \phi$ and only moving along the radius for fixed $\phi$ we have $dx = \cos \phi dr$ and $dy = \sin \phi dr$ and $dx + dy = (\cos \phi + \sin \phi) dr \le \sqrt{2} dr$ for $\phi = \pi/4$.
So I would run in that direction.

Comment: I'm not sure running will make you get cold most rapidly ;-)